# Setting timezone for timestamp data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a frequently changing pandas dataframe of data that looks like this:

```
         date name  time       timezone
0  2016-08-01  aaa  0900     Asia/Tokyo
1  2016-08-04  bbb  1200  Europe/Berlin
2  2016-08-05  ccc  1400  Europe/London
```

The date, time and timezone refer to a delivery date that is often for an overseas location, with the name being the name of the client company.

The plan is to take this data and create a `datetime_local` column that incorporates the time zone shown in the `timezone` column of dataframe. Then from that I want to add a column `datetime_london` that contains that date and time, but expressed in terms of the time and date in London.

I have got most of the way there but when calling `tz_localize` I end up with a `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()` which suggests to me that I'm not treating the column with the timezone correctly.

Any suggestions as to how to proceed?

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['2016-08-01','2016-08-04','2016-08-05'],
                          'time':['0900','1200','1400'],
                          'timezone':['Asia/Tokyo','Europe/Berlin','Europe/London'],
                          'name':['aaa','bbb','ccc']}
)
print(mydf)
mydf["datetime"] = mydf["date"].map(str) + " " + mydf["time"]
mydf.datetime = pd.to_datetime(mydf.datetime)
mydf.index = mydf.datetime
print(mydf)
mydf["datetime_local"] = mydf.datetime
mydf.datetime_local.tz_localize(mydf.timezone)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_to_local_time(row):
    return pd.to_datetime(row.datetime).tz_localize(row.timezone)

def convert_to_london_time(row):
    return pd.to_datetime(row.datetime_local).tz_convert('Europe/London')

mydf = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['2016-08-01','2016-08-04','2016-08-05'],
                          'time':['0900','1200','1400'],
                          'timezone':['Asia/Tokyo','Europe/Berlin','Europe/    London'],
                          'name':['aaa','bbb','ccc']}
)
print(mydf)
```

Output:

```
         date name  time       timezone
0  2016-08-01  aaa  0900     Asia/Tokyo
1  2016-08-04  bbb  1200  Europe/Berlin
2  2016-08-05  ccc  1400  Europe/London
```

Add `datetime_local` column

```
mydf["datetime"] = mydf["date"].map(str) + " " + mydf["time"]
mydf['datetime_local'] = mydf.apply(convert_to_local_time, axis=1)
print(mydf)
```

Output:

```
         date name  time       timezone         datetime  \
0  2016-08-01  aaa  0900     Asia/Tokyo  2016-08-01 0900   
1  2016-08-04  bbb  1200  Europe/Berlin  2016-08-04 1200   
2  2016-08-05  ccc  1400  Europe/London  2016-08-05 1400   

              datetime_local  
0  2016-08-01 09:00:00+09:00  
1  2016-08-04 12:00:00+02:00  
2  2016-08-05 14:00:00+01:00
```

Add `datetime_london` column

```
mydf['datetime_london'] = mydf.apply(convert_to_london_time, axis=1)
print('After adding datetime_london:')
print(mydf)
```

Output:

```
         date name  time       timezone         datetime  \
0  2016-08-01  aaa  0900     Asia/Tokyo  2016-08-01 0900   
1  2016-08-04  bbb  1200  Europe/Berlin  2016-08-04 1200   
2  2016-08-05  ccc  1400  Europe/London  2016-08-05 1400   

              datetime_local           datetime_london  
0  2016-08-01 09:00:00+09:00 2016-08-01 01:00:00+01:00  
1  2016-08-04 12:00:00+02:00 2016-08-04 11:00:00+01:00  
2  2016-08-05 14:00:00+01:00 2016-08-05 14:00:00+01:00
```

Answer (score 5):

While the previous answers work perfectly, when faced with this problem dealing with big data, the apply method was a bit inefficient (for a 10^6 order of magnitude of rows). The apply method processing row by row was taking me 10-15 minutes dealing with that scale. If you have a really small ratio of unique values for the timezone col, compared to the number of rows in your dataframe, this code is a lot more efficient:

```
for tz in df['timezone'].unique():    #iterates over each unique value of timezone in the dataframe
    mask = df['timezone'] == tz       #selects all rows with current unique tz value
    df.loc[mask,'datetime_local'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.loc[mask, 'datetime']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert(tz)
```

The last line of code converts the `datetime` column to `DatetimeIndex`, which makes that `datetime` UTC and `tz-naive` (if it wasn't already). Therefore, `tz_localize('UTC')` is required, since `tz_convert` does not work with `tz-naive` datetimes.

I know it's an old question but I really needed a faster solution for this and I think my answer might help people that come after me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [12]: mydf.apply(lambda x: x.datetime_local.tz_localize(x.timezone), axis=1)
Out[12]:
datetime
2016-08-01 09:00:00    2016-08-01 09:00:00+09:00
2016-08-04 12:00:00    2016-08-04 12:00:00+02:00
2016-08-05 14:00:00    2016-08-05 14:00:00+01:00
dtype: object
```